# Getting error : Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `profile` on serializer `UserSerializer`

Tags: python, django

i am new here in `django python` so pardon me for my silly  mistakes, When i try to run api  `/api/v1/users/`  getting error : `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field`profile`on serializer UserSerializer.` , here i have placed my whole code, i know i did some little mistake, but i didn't find it yet, can anyone please look my code and help me to resolve this issue ? any help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Songs
from .models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SongsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Songs
        fields = ("title", "artist")


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('title', 'dob', 'address', 'country', 'city', 'zip', 'photo')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'profile')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        profile = instance.profile

        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.save()

        profile.title = profile_data.get('title', profile.title)
        profile.dob = profile_data.get('dob', profile.dob)
        profile.address = profile_data.get('address', profile.address)
        profile.country = profile_data.get('country', profile.country)
        profile.city = profile_data.get('city', profile.city)
        profile.zip = profile_data.get('zip', profile.zip)
        profile.photo = profile_data.get('photo', profile.photo)
        profile.save()
        return instance;
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

import rest_framework.generics
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Songs
from .serializers import SongsSerializer
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import viewsets

class ListSongsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Provides a get method handler.
    """
    queryset = Songs.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongsSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): #generics.ListAPIView, generics.RetrieveAPIView
    # viewsets.ModelViewSet
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    #print(queryset.count());
    #exit()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

from django.db import models


class Songs(models.Model):
    # song title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    # name of artist or group/band
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.title, self.artist)


class Test(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # song title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    # name of artist or group/band
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.title, self.dob, self.address, self.country, self.city, self.zip, self.photo)
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any link between User and UserProfile.

Comment: Can you help me for that ?

Comment: what should i do now for that ?

Comment: You presumably want a OneToOneField from UserProfile to User.

Comment: Can you explain me by code

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) in the comments, you should provide relationship between your `UserProfile` and django's `User` model.

First edit your **models.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)  # you may need to remove primary_key=True based on your use-case
    # ...
```

and don't forget `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Also edit this parts of your **serializers.py**:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'dob', 'address', 'country', 'city', 'zip', 'photo')
```

Comment: in userprofile table i have this fields profile,title,dob,address,country,city,zip,photo and profile field is foreign key of user table and user table have this fields id,password,last_login,is_superuser,username,first_name,last_name,email,is_staff,is_active,date_joined which is standard field of the user,

Comment: Dear @NikulPanchal have you applied migration,  `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: Is the same error showing up? Where _exactly_ the error is complaining about?